# How do you optimise your Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

Well... simple question, right? But with no so simple answers.
In firefox i use firebug console (profile) but... what to do in other browsers? Like Internet Explorer / Opera / Safari (on windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use JavaScript optimizers

- http://js-optimizer.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.xtreeme.com/javascript-optimizer/

Answer (score 4):

This particular problem solves itself over time. ;-)

Version 8 of the Internet Explorer (currently in beta 2) ships with a built-in JavaScript profiler. The next Safari version will probably also include one since its rendering engine, WebKit, now has one as part of its [Web Inspector](http://webkit.org/blog/148/web-inspector-update/).

Answer (score 3):

This page contains some suggestions:

http://www.newearthonline.co.uk/index.php?page=article&article=338&pagenum=2

Answer (score 3):

Yahoo provides a [Javascript profiler](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/profiler/), you may want have a look at that one.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a simple question to answer.But certain things has to be keep in mind while using or working with javascript.There are no hard and fast rules but I can think of some which
I had done previously.Avoid circular refernces of javascript objects.This is particularly important to avoid memory leaks.Another important thing is garbage collecting of objects when they are no more referenced. You can Google for optimizing ways some are effective too!!

Answer (score 0):

Try out Firebug Lite. I am not sure whether it will solve your purpose fully.

http://getfirebug.com/lite.html